# How to add other values to DateEntry?

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to add to DateEntry another option like in the combobox, when you press combobox it shows a list of option. I would need here also one additional option. Is it possible or is it another option

```
from tkinter import *
from tkcalendar import DateEntry
root = Tk()
e7 = DateEntry(root,values="Text", width=12,bg="darkblue",fg="white",year=2020,state="readonly",date_pattern="yyyy-mm-dd")
e7.grid(row=7,column=1,padx=20,pady=5,sticky=W)
root.mainloop()
```

Or can I do the way around to add DateEntry to combobox?

```
  cb = ttk.Combobox(root,values=("Simple text",DateEntry))
  cb.grid(row=0,column=0)
```

[image]

Comment: what option do you want to add?

Comment: Only text, when I roll out dateentry it should be above calender

Comment: calendar and datentry are not same? i would recomend to use `from tkcalendary import Calendar` then?

Comment: hmm how to explain... I want when I click on DateEntry it drops a calender. And I would like above this calender a line of text like on Combobox.

Comment: You want a combobox above the calendar window? just like normally, you can create a combobx and `place()` or `grid()` it near the calendar right? Maybe include a picture of what you want to make it more clear

Comment: Yes, excactly that I mean

Comment: Maybe due to the lack of understanding, your code included does have a combobox on top of the calendar right? or do u want a combobox to not choose date? for someother purpose?

Comment: I added picture

Comment: So if they choose dateentry, you want to popopen the calendar?

Comment: yes that is the idea

Comment: Ill add a demo answer for now, tell me if its what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this helps you

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkcalendar import DateEntry

root = Tk()


def pop(event):
    e7 = DateEntry(root, values="Text", width=12, bg="darkblue",
                   fg="white", year=2020, state="readonly", date_pattern="yyyy-mm-dd")
    e7.grid(row=1, column=1, padx=20, pady=5, sticky=W)


combo = ttk.Combobox(root, values=('Sample Text', 'Date'))
combo.grid(row=1, column=2)
combo.bind('<<ComboboxSelected>>', pop)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: But when you press combobox could be the second option calender but calendar shows after clicling on combobox as the second option

Comment: What did you mean? I dint get you. When do you want it show then?

Comment: hmm maybe pack dateEntry to variable and give as second value to combobox

Comment: actually, as long as `pop()` is not run, dateEntry will be undefined, so passing in a variable to combobox isnt a possible option

Answer (score -1):

```
from tkinter import *
from tkcalendar import DateEntry
root = Tk()
e7 = DateEntry(root,values="Text", width=12,bg="darkblue",fg="white",year=2020,state="readonly",date_pattern="yyyy-mm-dd")
e7.grid(row=7,column=1,padx=20,pady=5,sticky=W)
root.mainloop()
```